# Circular import error python

Tags: python

estoy aprendiendo a usar Flask y Sqlalchemy y haciendo unas pruebas me sale este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\sqlalchemy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_engine' from partially initialized module 'sqlalchemy' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\sqlalchemy.py)
```

**Mi código**

```py
from datetime import datetime

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionMaker

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DataTime

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

Session = sessionmaker(engine)
Session = Session()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: Por lo que puedo interpretar, tu script se llama `sqlalchemy.py`, e intentas importar `sqlalchemy`. Solución: guarda tu script con otro nombre, por ejemplo `pruebasqlalchemy.py`

Comment: Muchas gracias, en este momento hago la prueba =)